# Return for the first view after I'm on the fifth view of an iOS application in Xcode

Tags: xcode, view, switch-statement, viewcontroller, uiswitch

I'm fairly new to xcode, and am creating a single view application with five views (xib files). I am not using navigation controller or storyboard for two reasons. 
If I use Storyboard, I am forced to have my other views be UIView files. These dont have

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
```

Which prevents me from loading a few timers I have in my application.

I am able to navigate from the first page to the second and so on, all the way to the fifth page/view with the following code.

```
-(IBAction)pagethree {
    countdown=[[Countdown alloc] initWithNibName:@"Countdown" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:countdown.view];  
}
```

However when I want to go back from the fifth view to the first page I run into a problem.
My first view is called ViewController. If I try the code from above, my app is full of errors.

I also tried using

```
-(IBAction)back {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview]; 
}
```

but that only took me back one view.

My fifth view controller is called Statistics and the first one is called ViewController.
What can I code to get from back from the last view to the first?

Thanks

Comment: Hey hiten, I would defiantly recommend using story boards, you can create segues to and from view controllers with no code, the storyboard elements each link to a new uiviewcontroller and always either call viewDidLoad, or alternatively call viewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear which work just as fine to put a timer etc in... If you would like me to post some more resources about storyboards etc let me know but marianos answer is correct, navigation controllers are very powerful. Best of luck, T

Comment: Taylor, thank you for the suggestion. I am in the process of recoding the program with storyboards, and will let you know if I run into any problems!

Answer (score 1):

First, to answer your question, you need to do a **removeFromSuperview** (or similar) for each **addSubview:** you did. Each time you do addSubview, you're placing your new screen "on top" of the last one, like a stack. When you reach your 5th view, you have 4 other views "behind" it. (Actually, that's not exactly what addSubview does, but I'm just describing the effect in your particular situation).

But I think you're doing it wrong... You should read more about storyboards and navigation controllers. Both are used with UIViewController and support out of the box what you're trying to do by hand. For example, using a navigation controller, to push a new view controller you can do:

```
[navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

You can do that as many times as you want. Then, to go back once, you do:

```
[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And to go back directly to the first one:

```
[navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.